# How to properly use select2 in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, select, jquery-select2

This question is not a duplicate because using the methods in other (similar) questions does not work.

I have a select box:

```
<select id="order-statuses" name="order-status" class="order-statuses" >
                    <option value="all" <?php selected( 'all', $current_value );?> ><?php esc_html_e( 'All', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></option>
                    <?php
                    if( ! empty ( $order_statuses ) ) :
                        foreach( $order_statuses as $order_status => $label ) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $order_status ); ?>" <?php selected( $order_status, $current_value );?> ><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></option>
                    <?php
                        endforeach;
                    endif;
                    ?>
                </select>
```

I am trying to get select2 working with this select but nothing I try is working, select2 appears to load the CSS and JS files correctly in the head of my site, and there are no errors in the console.

I've tried:

```
function enqueue_select2_jquery() {
    wp_register_style( 'select2css', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.8/select2.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_register_script( 'select2', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.8/select2.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'select2css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'select2' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_select2_jquery' );
function select2jquery_inline() {
    ?>
<style type="text/css">
.select2-container {margin: 0 2px 0 2px;}
.tablenav.top #doaction, #doaction2, #post-query-submit {margin: 0px 4px 0 4px;}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if( $( 'select' ).length > 0 ) {
        $( 'select' ).select2();
        $( document.body ).on( "click", function() {
             $( 'select' ).select2({
                  theme: "classic"
             });
          });
    }
});
</script>
    <?php
 }
add_action( 'admin_head', 'select2jquery_inline' );
```

Which should be using select2 on ALL selects sitewise but that doesn't do anything to my select box. It doesn't add a class. It doesn't change appearance. Nothing.

I've also tried (in code and manually in the console with no errors);

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
    <script>

        jQuery('select2').select2({
            theme: "classic"
        });

    </script>
<?php } );
```

After assigning the `class='select2'` tot he select element in the code. Nothing has any effect and without errors I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix your `class` name with a `dot` in `JS`. So if your class is named as `select2`, your code instead of

```
jQuery('select2').select2({
    theme: "classic"
});
```

should be

```
jQuery('.select2').select2({ //See the Dot
    theme: "classic"
});
```

In the HTML that you shared, your select has class `order-statuses`. So JS to initialize `select2` would be

```
jQuery('.order-statuses').select2();
```

Comment: I think that was just a hasty copy on my part to show I tried via class and element. In the second group, the select is supposed to be finding all elements and turning them into select2.

Comment: My issue appears to a loading issue or load timing issue. I think WordPress is loading the select after the jQuery runs in this instance. I have it partly working messing around with that so I think that's the case. Thanks for your help though.